# Tool for managing Outlook 2007 contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts

I have to manage my boss' Outlook contacts, but I don't have an Outlook license (or rather, I don't really need it).

Now I wondered whether there is a good and fully functional tool which allows me to manage Outlook contacts the way (or better, simpler) than Outlook does it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Free Contact Manager](http://www.exchangewise.com/Free_Contact_Manager.htm)

Or see several tools here:

http://www.slipstick.com/addins/contact_management.asp

Comment: These look good. However, they seem to all be Outlook add-ins or similar. And that's exactly the point. I don't want to use Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

What about some kind of database tool?  Can you access your boss' Outlook to export occasionally?  This way you can manage without using Outlook directly.

Comment: That might work. Do you have an example? And it should probably be enough to export once and then from time to time import from my machine to his Outlook.

Comment: I was thinking Access because it's in the suite and easy to use.  You could use Excel, as well.  But maybe you want to move in the direction of a CRM, like SugarCRM?  What info do you have in each contact entry?

Comment: Mainly addresses, email and birthdays. Plus I have some email lists...